# Find comma space year but ignore comma year without space

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to read in a file and every time `, year` is found it prints it out.  For example if it finds `, 2003` it will print that out, but if it finds `,2003` it will ignore it.  I originally used a split and was able to get the year to match up, but when I added the `,` I realized that it looked at it like two different words so I dont think that would work.

Here is my code:

```
import string
import re

while True:
    filename=raw_input('Enter a file name: ')
    if filename == 'exit':
        break
    try:
        file = open(filename, 'r') 
        text=file.read() 
        file.close() 
    except:
        print('file does not exist')
    else:
        p=re.compile('^\,\s(19|20)\d\d$')//this is my regular expression
        print(text)
        m=p.search(text)
        if m:
                print(m.groups())
```

Comment: Is this a question? Why not use a scanner-generator?

Comment: yes, I am a little stuck on what to do.  can you explain a scanner-generator I am new to python

Comment: It might be helpful to show some example input. In any case, a scanner generator is a general computer science concept. Try googling for it: http://www.google.com/search?q=scanner+generator+for+python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to search the file for the regex rather than match the entire file contents, remove `^` and `$` from the regex.
2. If you want more than one match per file, use `finditer` or `findall` instead of `search`.
3. Use raw string when specifying the regex: `p=re.compile(r',\s(19|20)\d\d')`

Example:

```
for m in re.finditer(r',\s((19|20)\d\d)', text):
    print m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "foo bar, 2003, 2006,1923, derp"
>>> p = re.compile(r',\s((?:19|20)\d\d)')
>>> p.findall(text)
['2003', '2006']
```

Simplified example. First of all, remove the anchors (`^` and `$`) and use `findall` instead of `search` to find all matches. I also used `?:` to designate a non-matching group (it won't show up in the results) and made the year a group instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you just add a `*` to the `\s` in your regex, I think it should work. This will make it match zero or more whitespace characters, instead of exactly one. If you only want it to match zero or one, add a `+` instead.